Find the shortest path from a word to another
Imagine you want to find one among the shortest path between two words of the same length.
Every step of the path is the change of a character.
The new word must be in the dictionary.txt file used.
An example from LANE to BODY could be:
LANELONEBONEBONYBODY
I wrote a simple Python code to accomplish this task.
My code is a little bit slow for words of 6 or more characters and I'm not even sure that the path found is the shortest possible.
Could anyone review my code and improve it?
from collections import deque
import time


def load_words(word_length):
    with open('dictionary.txt', encoding="utf8") as file:
        words = {line.strip() for line in file if len(line.strip()) == word_length}
    return words


def get_neighbors(word, word_set):
    neighbors = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        for char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            if char != word[i]:
                new_word = word[:i] + char + word[i + 1:]
                if new_word in word_set:
                    neighbors.append(new_word)
    return neighbors


def find_shortest_path(start, end):
    if start == end:
        return [start]

    word_set = load_words(len(start))

    if start not in word_set or end not in word_set:
        return None

    queue = deque([(start, [start])])
    visited = {start}

    while queue:
        current_word, path = queue.popleft()

        for neighbor in get_neighbors(current_word, word_set):
            if neighbor == end:
                return path + [neighbor]
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                queue.append((neighbor, path + [neighbor]))

    return None


start_word = input("Insert the starting word: ")
end_word = input("Insert the ending word: ")
start_time = time.time()
if not start_word.isalpha():
    print(f"Invalid input: {start_word} contains not alphabetic characters.")
elif not end_word.isalpha():
    print(f"Invalid input: {end_word} contains not alphabetic characters.")
elif len(start_word) != len(end_word):
    print(f"Invalid input: {start_word} and {end_word} must be the same length")
else:
    start_word = start_word.lower()
    end_word = end_word.lower()
    path_found = find_shortest_path(start_word, end_word)
    if path_found:
        print(f"\nMinimum path length is: {len(path_found) - 1}")
        print("\n".join(path_found).upper())
    else:
        print(f"\nDoesnt' exist any path from {start_word} to {end_word}.")
print(f"Time taken: {time.time() - start_time}")

PS: The game that i want to solve is usually called Laddergram.

What do you define as shortest path? Please clarify your question.

This sounds a lot like Levenshtein distance. Or is there a difference?

If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the Code Review StackExchange.

Levenshtein package is your friend here
import Levenshtein

start_word = 'LANE'
end_word = 'BODY'

edit_list = Levenshtein.editops('LANE', 'BODY')
temp = start_word
print(temp)
for idx in range(len(edit_list)):
    temp = Levenshtein.apply_edit(edit_list[idx:idx+1], temp, 'BODY')
    print(temp)

LANE
BANE
BONE
BODE
BODY

Traversing between words in some dictionary
Now re-reading your question, it is not specified clearly, but if you want each "intermediate" word to be present in some dictionary, this will be far more complicated.
I would start by creating graph of words, each node a word, each edge being set between each "neighbouring" words. Then traversing such graph is relatively easy. Take a look at networkx package
